# Android crashlytics non fatal logs

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have integrated firebase crashlytics in my app. I am able to see crashes in the dashboard that have been caught or thrown an exception but the user has not experienced the crash(where the app closes).
Is this expected behavior?
Is there a way I can disable it?

Comment: Do you mean Firebase crashlytics doesn't log the crash error that closes an app?

Comment: @Venus No I meant the other way. It records logs that don't close the app

Comment: If you record exceptions or throwables manually, example like `try / catch` or via any other means, it is logged as a `Non-fatal` as it doesn't crash the app.